# Could not delete VPC Subnets associated with a DBSubnetGroup due to Unchangeable VPC Endpoint and NetworkInterfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-serverless

I realized in one of our projects that I needed to move an AppSync service and an RDS Serverless Aurora (MySQL-compatible) Database Cluster to a new set of subnets.  We use the Serverless Framework for all our projects, so all changes were made to `serverless.yml` files.  I created two new subnets in different AZs, moved the AppSync resolvers and Lambdas to the new subnets, and modified the DBSubnetGroup to use the new subnets.  I figured these changes would mean the old subnets were no longer in use and could be deleted.

After making the changes, I realized that I couldn't delete the original subnet pair because they were still associated with two network interfaces used by a VPC Endpoint automatically created by the RDS DB SubnetGroup.  Since these resources were created by AWS on my behalf, I couldn't modify the network interfaces.  When trying to detach them from the subnets, I would receive the error message `You are not allowed to manage 'ela-attach' attachments.`  When I tried to delete the VPC Endpoint, I received the error message `Operation is not allowed for requester-managed VPC endpoints for the service {DNS_NAME}.`

I understand why AWS would create these resources.  However, I do not understand why the network interfaces were still linked to the original subnet pair AFTER I had modified the DB SubnetGroup to remove the original subnets and add new subnets created in the AZs I really wanted.  I confirmed that the database was still accessible from my data services, even though the VPC endpoint would indicate that the traffic went through the old subnets that were not associated with the SubnetGroup.  While doing experiments in my Dev environment, I found the only way to correct the situation was to create a NEW SubnetGroup and recreate the Serverless DB Cluster (since one cannot modify a cluster to point to a new SubnetGroup).  Once the new Cluster was created, a different VPC endpoint existed with network interfaces associated with the new subnet pairs.

In the end, this question is more or less academic as our solution is not yet in production, and I can either recreate the test/prod databases from scratch through ORM code or simply take and restore a snapshot.  However, I'd like to know what I could have done differently.  Thanks for any input!

**References I used:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/change-vpc-rds-db-instance/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-vpc-aurora-cluster/
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-db-subnet-group/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Modifying.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-cluster.html